# Sorting JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting, object

Having a problem trying to sort a JSON object. Basically, people can add products in any random order to our order form, but the order it shows in the summary needs to be how we want them to be positioned (not the order they select them), so thats why I need to sort by 'id' (or we'll sort by a 'pos' field later)

Essentially, I need to sort by the id ascending. 1,2,103 instead of 2,103,1

I seem to be having issues because the index into the individual objects are numbers (or just the fact that they're there...).

I need to do something along the lines of array.sort(function(a,b){ return a.id-b.id }); but I'm presuming that doesn't work because 1, its not an array (its an object), and 2, it has those pesky indexes (that i need for another part of my code)...

Any ideas????

```
var products = {
    "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "price": "119",
        "quantity": "1",
        "thumb": "img\/store\/comp-08n.png"
    },
    "103": {
        "id": "103",
        "price": "109",
        "quantity": "1",
        "thumb": "img\/store\/basketballhoop.png"
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "price": "309",
        "quantity": "1",
        "thumb": "img\/store\/comp-08.png"
    }
};
```

Comment: Objects are unordered by nature (i.e., there's no "sorting" for a property bag); what's the result you expect?

Comment: I think he's using an object as an associative array, instead of a "sparse array", which is what he really wants.

Comment: Use an Array of objects. Also, checkout underscore.js.  It's pretty nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How many items do you need in your orders? You can safely sort 10'000 items in a Javascript array without much of speed issues. Why don't you work with a real array instead?

You could even inject custom properties to it, roughly something like

```
var products = [...];

products.findById = function(id) {
   for (var i=0, len=this.length; i<len; i++) {
      if (id == this[i].id) return this[i];
   }
   return null;
};

alert( products.findById(103).price );   // -> 119
```

and add predefined sorters like

```
products.sortById = function() {
    this.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.id - b.id;
    });
};

products.sortById();   // sort array by product id
```

** **EDIT** **

On your PHP side, you might have something like :

```
$products = array(
    2 => array( 'id' => 2, ... ),
    103 => array( 'id' => 103, ... ),
    1 => array( 'id' => 1, ... ),
);

// get a JSON array
$jsonArray = json_encode(array_values($products));
```

will return what you need.

** **NOTE** **

You should not explicitly set indexes when adding new items in your array. Use the array's `push` function, like

```
products.push({id:123, price:200.49, quantity:1, thumb:'/path/to/file'});
```

Removing an item is a bit tricky, however, something like :

```
products.removeById = function(id) {
   for (var i=0, len=this.length; i<len; i++) {
      if (id == this[i].id) return this.splice(i, 1)[0];
   }
   return null;
};

products.removeById(123);    // -> returns the removed element! or null if nothing was removed
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rh67Q/1/) (use Chrome developper tools for console output).

Comment: Like 20 probably at most...

Well, does PHP have a function to dump an associative array into a JS array or would I just make one? At the moment I'm just using json_encode

Comment: php has json_encode() which returns a Javascript array if all the indexes are all integers (see the manual)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that Yanick, very helpful :) I got it working using your sorter and getting PHP to dump it as an array of objects instead of an object of objects

Comment: glad I could help. See the latest edits for more details (if you haven't already done so)

Comment: Thanks again! I just noticed the findBy is how I would find the appropriate index rather than setting it (that didnt sink in before lol). Would you say the performance difference between sorting my array at the start into the proper indexes (using a for products.length newarr[products[i].id] = products[i]) so I can access via product[id] is better or worse (speed wise) than running your findById function every single time a product is changed?

Comment: Nevermind. There appear to be too many issues with remapping the indexes of the array. I'll go with your findById method :)

Comment: unless you *really* need to perform critical calculations per second, I would recommend in any case to look for other solutions, but with only a dozen items, this solution is, in my opinion, exactly what you need indeed. I used to try and optimize whatever I could before, but now I follow a simple rule one teacher taught us regarding UIs: the user won't mind the wait (if there is a wait) if you tell them how long they have to wait. And I realized that, most of the time, the wait is always less than a second. Everyone is happy :)

Answer (score 4):

There are two types of collections in JavaScript and in JSON:

1. key/value map (object) - unordered collection and
2. Array - index/value map (array) - ordered collection.

By definition only array can be sorted. Use array.

Comment: Then how for example do I access the price of an id without having to know the order of the output? e.g. i cannot just do product[1][1] is price or whatever... :\

Comment: @Benno you would just do product[1].price

Comment: So my array would look like this? 
var products = [1:{price:109,name:'Thing'}]; Cos that doesnt seem to work.. its weird, I've never created an array like that before lol :\

Comment: @Benno, use this: `var a = []; a[1] = {price:109,name:'Thing'};` etc.
Most JS implementations use so called sparse arrays so you can create array with "holes".

Comment: @Benno No, since arrays are ordered, you don't need to supply indexes when declaring them.  So the above array is something like [null, {price:109, name:"Thing"}] (assuming you wanted your object indexed at 1 rather than 0) - assuming of course you're talking about a JSON array.

Comment: A "sparse array" would be excatly the same as using an object. It's stored the same, handles the same, `length` is no longer sensical to use. You're not using the array as an array then.

Comment: Ahhh ok... thanks for that guys! :) I think I'll go with this array way, hopefully it doesnt break too much of my code lol.

Comment: @Adam Bergmark: `array.length` will tell you max index of your elements. And you still can sort it. Or I do not understand what you actually meant. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/hhQ63/

Comment: Thanks for posting c-smile, I was just wondering why it was running through my loop 104 times when I was using $.each lol.

Answer (score 2):

recursive solution, doesn't deal with arrays though, javascript

```
var alphabetizeJSON = function(obj){
    var key,
        array = [],
        stringifiedValuesObj = {},
        jsonKeyVal = "",
        i,
        keyName;

    for (key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === "object"){
            stringifiedValuesObj[key] = "" + alphabetizeJSON(obj[key]);
        } else {
            obj[key] = obj[key].replace(/\"/gi,'\\\"');
        }
        array.push(key);
    }

    array.sort();

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        keyName = array[i];
        jsonKeyVal += '"' + keyName + '": ';
        jsonKeyVal += stringifiedValuesObj[keyName] ? stringifiedValuesObj[keyName] : '"' + obj[keyName] + '"';
        if (i < array.length - 1 ) {
            jsonKeyVal += ',';
        }
    }

    return '{ ' + jsonKeyVal + '}';
};
```

Comment: I got the following error:

`ReferenceError: orderJSON is not defined`

Comment: Thanks, fixed.  I changed the name of the function

Answer (score 0):

Check out `JSONArray`s. They might be what you need. http://json.org/java/

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you should be able to use an array instead of an object for this job, and that will solve a lot of your difficulty.

If you can't do that, you can convert the object into an array to give it ordering... something like this:

```
var a = []
for (var p in obj) {
  a[+p] = obj[p]
}
```

If you can't do that, you could dynamically add the information to the page in the order you want (the following is a bad idea)...

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  if (obj[i] !== undefined) {
    add_to_page(obj[i])  //define this somewhere
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that actually works haha win! Although I realise its kind of wasting resoruces (minimal as they are), so I'll try to convert it to an array first, but if I get fed up I'll do it this way :)