# Trouble Sorting JSON

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I have a JSON object like the following:

```
{"Data": {
     "290": {
             ...
            }
     "300": {
             ...
            }
     "281": {
             ...
            }
         }
 }
```

How would I sort this JSON based on the top container keys (i.e. "290", "300", "281")?

Edit: So I used

`$.getJSON('current/csf.txt', function(data) { arr = data["Data"]; }`

And it sorted them based on the key. Why did this happen?

Comment: Don´t ever try to sort keys of an object!

Comment: Is the sort is numeric (1000 > 200) or alphanumeric ("200" > "1000")?

Comment: Amberlamps: I know I know. But this order is coming from higher up in the food chain!
William R: alphanumeric would work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting JSON Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147547/sorting-json-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've tagged this "JavaScript" so I assume you mean "A JavaScript object generated from this JSON".

In which case:

1. Loop over the property names (with a `for in` loop).
2. Use them to populate an array.
3. Sort the array.
4. Use the array as a map.

(You can't store ordered data in an object).

If you want to store the results in JSON, then you will need to change your data structure (and use an array (of objects)). Objects are explicitly unordered.

Answer (score 4):

Your structure is wrong, it should be something like:

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "id": "290"
    },
    {
      "id": "300"
    },
    {
      "id": "282"
    }
  ]
}
```

Objects are for unordered data. Use arrays for ordered data. And the array is really easy to sort here:

```
obj.Data.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.id - b.id;
});
```

You can convert to this structure like so:

```
 function copyProps(dest, src) {
     for (var key in src) {
         dest[key] = src[key];
     }
     return dest;
 }

 var newData = [];

 for (var key in obj.Data) {
     newData.push(copyProps({
         id: key
     }, obj.Data[key]));
 }
```

Comment: The structure is wrong. That is the first thing I said when I received this project! However the developer who uses it wont change it -_-

Comment: @michael_clarke you can loop through the object to convert it to this structure and then use this structure though. If he won't change it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems like Quentin's advice worked best. Now off to try to convince him to change his structure!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Amberlamps comment, you shouldn't be trying to sort the keys of an object, *but* if you wanted to for some reason you might take a look at [underscore.js's sortBy method](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy)

Comment: I'm sorting them to troubleshoot some issues we are having with a new system in generating the JSON. Sorting them should put the files in the same order so then we can do a file diff to see whats different.

Comment: Alright then you'll want to follow Quentin's advice; convert it to an array which is sortable (and then if you wanted to you could use _.sortBy() but you're better off using the built in [.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method

Comment: Whenever I converted it to an Array it sorted itself. Why would that occur?

Comment: Because Objects are not sorted so when you iterate through them it's equally within the spec to iterate through them in a sorted manner (which some user agents/browser might choose to do) as to iterate in a seemingly random manner. Most seem to sort them numerically by key.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you COULD sort object attributes, there's no guarantee that you could read them back in sorted order. In Javascript, object attributes are not stored in a specific order; an object simply has attributes.

You cannot use array index notation to access object attributes, so the notion of sorting object attributes by key is moot.