# jQuery: ordering an array from a json one

Tags: jquery, json

reqI have a json like this:

```
[{"type":"checkbox",
 "title":"An example",
 "values":
  {"2": {"value":"val1", "required":"true"}, 
   "3": {"value":"val2", "required":"false"}, 
   "4": {"value":"val3", "required":"false"}, 
  }
}, and so on]
```

I have a jquery function

```
var fromJson = function (json) {
    var values = '';
    var options = false;
    // Parse json
    $(json).each(function () {
      // type "checkbox"
      if (this.type === 'checkbox') {
        options = [this.title];
        values = [];
        $.each(this.values, function () {
          values.push([this.value, this.required]);
        });
      }
      // other types                
       ...
    });
};
```

I would that `$.each(this.values, function () {
              values.push([this.value, this.baseline]);
            });` 
push the values in the right order, how could I do?

Is there a way to order `values` according to "2", "3", "4",... before doing the push?

**EDIT**

I've resolved with

```
   $.each(this.values, function (key) {
          values[key-2]=[this.value, this.required];
        });
```

Comment: Why don't you sort the table afterwards ?

Comment: What's a "jquery array"? Also, what you're calling "a json" is not json, it's an object (at least, the `json` parameter in your function is expecting an object and not json).

Comment: googled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147547/sorting-json-object

Comment: @nnnnnn: you're right. I'll try to examine the passed object.

Comment: @nnnnnn: it's JSON-encoded data, obtained by $.getJSON

Comment: It _was_ JSON-encoded data. By the time your function sees it it has already been parsed to created an object, at which point it is not JSON anymore (JSON is a _string_ encoding).

Comment: @nnnnnn: How could I know how that object is? How can I print it on the console?

Comment: @RomainBraun: what table? The json represents a form. In the HTML I lose the checkboxes order.

Comment: @Cricket ..Well you're pushing values into the `values`table. Just sort it afterwards.

Comment: @RomainBraun: At that point, I have no more the "numbers". I've resolved in another way.